# How to compare strings and get added lines

Tags: python, diff

Given two strings in Python, `a` and `b` (where `b` is like `a` but with some lines added), how would one compare them and get the line(s) added to `b`?

For example, if `a` is

```
Line one
And line two
And this would be line three
```

and `b` is

```
Line one
And line two
An added line!
And this would be line three
```

it would return `'An added line!'`.

If any lines are removed or changed, it should return `None`. For example, if `b` was instead

```
Line one
And line two (but changed!)
An added line!
And this would be line three
```

it should not return `'An added line!'` but rather `None`.

Essentially, all lines in `a` should still be present in the same order in `b`, but with extra line(s) added in. (If some lines in `a` are not in `b` or if they are in a different order, then `None` should be returned.) How would one get those extra line(s)?

Thank you!

My current code (doesn't check order):

```
def get_addition(old, new):
  old_lines = set(old.split('\n'))
  new_lines = set(new.split('\n'))
  if old_lines < new_lines:
    return new_lines - old_lines
  else:
    return None
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service. We expect you to make an effort to solve your problem and share your code with us (including expected and actual results) if you are seeking help.

Comment: Your question is too broad and not necessarily simple. Just search for file diff algorithms

Comment: It feels like [homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).

Comment: I added my current code. I'm also considering iterating through a list of new lines and checking for a match in a list of old lines, though this would be more complicated.

Comment: FYI you talk about the result being 'This is an added line' but that text is not actually present in the data. I presume you mean 'An added line!'. So, worth correcting your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a custom function:

```
def check_strings(a, b):
    lista = a.split("\n")
    listb = b.split("\n")

    #check if all lines in b are in a
    if not all(line in listb for line in enumerate(lista)):
        return None
    
    #check if the order is correct
    indices_b = [listb.index(line) for line in lista]
    if not all(idx <= indices_b[i+1] for i, idx in enumerate(indices_b[:-1])):
        return None
    
    #return differences in order
    else:
        return "\n".join([line for line in listb if line not in lista])
```

###### Example:

```
a = '''Line one
And line two
And this would be line three'''

b = '''Line one
And line two
An added line!
And this would be line three'''

c = '''Line one
And line two (but changed!)
An added line!
And this would be line three'''

>>> check_strings(a, b)
'An added line!'

>>> check_strings(a, c)
```

Comment: This works better than what I had, but it's still not quite what I'm looking for. `list(set(listb)-set(lista))` does not preserve duplicate lines or order, and checking `listb.index(line)>=i` catches many changes in order but not something like `_a = 'one\ntwo\nthree'` and `b = 'one\nanother\nthree\ntwo'`.

Comment: @tol - Edited. That should check that `b` is in the same order as `a`, as well as return the differences in order.